# How to use '[' as a symbol in python regular expressions

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a string like this,

```
a = '''hai stackoverflow. <help>//(good evening): value ="[i am new to 'python'], i need help"</help>'''
```

From this string, I need to extract the partial string from `<help>` to `</help>`.
Which means, my output should be

```
<help>//(good evening): value ="[i am new to 'python'], i need help"</help>
```

and i tried with this expression

```
re.search(r'<help> [\w:=">/-/\[\]]*',a).group()
```

but I am getting error as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#467>", line 1, in <module>
    re.search(r'<help> [\w:=">/-/\[\]]*',a).group()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: Include the error you are getting.

Comment: ... *what* error? Have you tried using a regex debugger like http://regex101.com?

Comment: *I am getting error* is a useless problem description unless you tell us what *error* you're getting. It's on your screen, right in front of your eyes. There is absolutely **no excuse** for you to not include it in your post.

Comment: That means that `re.search` didn't find anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an `AttributeError` because `re.search` returns `None` , and so it has no `group()` method .
If you change this line :

```
re.search(r'<help> [\w:=">/-/\[\]]*',a).group()
```

to this :

```
search_result = re.search(r'<help> [\w:=">/-/\[\]]*',a)
if search_result : 
    search_result = search_result.group()
```

you will get rid of the `AttributeError`

You can escape characters with `\` , but in this case you can get the desiered result much easier :

```
print(re.search('<help>(.*?)</help>', a).group())
<help>//(good evening): value ="[i am new to 'python'], i need help"</help>
```